# How can I run Chrome headless from protractor WITHOUT using a Selenium server

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I have Chrome working headless via a Selenium server by running `xvfb` bound to DISPLAY:10 and then running Selenium with a `DISPLAY=:10 webdriver-manager start`. So that's all fine.

I also have Chromedriver running directly from protractor by specifying `directConnect: true` in my protractor.conf.

What I'd like to do is a combination of the two, ie. run chromedriver directly (NO SELENIUM!), but somehow instruct it to run headless on DISPLAY :10.

In terms of topology, everything is run on the developer's PC. There are no servers involved. In a comment below, I mention a node server: this is being used to launch protractor instead of the more usual launching from the command line. I want protractor to be running on DISPLAY:0 so I can see its output, test failures etc. When it spawns chrome using chromedriver, I want chrome to be running on DISPLAY:10. My reason for doing this is that I want the chrome window to be bigger than my physical screen. See [How can I screenshot the full height of a mobile form factor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607359/how-can-i-screenshot-the-full-height-of-a-mobile-form-factor) for background.

Comment: Hi Andrew. It's not working because I don't know how to try to make it work. I can't find anywhere to configure the target DISPLAY for the launched chrome instance.

Comment: java doesn't come into it. protractor is a node application. DISPLAY for the node application is DISPLAY=:0 because protractor is running on my X display. It's when protractor spawns the chromedriver that I want the chromedriver to connect to DISPLAY=:10

Comment: Sorry, deleted confusing comment. Obviously stuck in Java mode...

Comment: I'm having trouble working out the topology. So this is all on one server? xvfb on :10, `DISPLAY=:10`, Sel Server, chromedriver, and node/protractor  - with your test calling Server / protractor remotely. Is that right? But you also say "DISPLAY for the node application is DISPLAY=:0", so is node/protractor and another chromedriver on a separate box? If this was all on one box, with DISPLAY=:10, then surely all graf would go through xvfb with no extra config. If not, surely you just need DISPLAY=otherBox:10 on the node box, assuming you don't want a separate xvfb there.

Comment: How are you launching your headless Chrome instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a "Doh!!!" moment of zen and the whole thing is much easier that I thought it would be.

I had conflated the stdout of node/protractor (which I want on my screen) with the X display of chrome (which I want headless on DISPLAY:10). Of course they are totally different!!!!

Simply prefixing protractor with DISPLAY=:10 eg.

```
DISPLAY=:10 protractor /installation_test/conf-c-direct-noserver.js
```

or, in my case since I'm running a node server which in turn spawns protractor, ...

```
DISPLAY=:10 npm start
```

So protractor runs in my terminal and I can watch stdout, whereas the DISPLAY=:10 is inherited down through the call layers and is eventually seen and understood by Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the topology is like this:

- Box A: `xvfb`, `DISPLAY=:10`, Selenium Server, chromedriver
- Box B: `DISPLAY=:0`, node, protractor (`directConnect: true`), chromedriver
- Box C: test runner.

I don't know how else it could be laid out, given that `DISPLAY` [is an environment variable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432255/what-is-display-environment-variable), not a parameter to be passed.

In which case, assuming you don't want a separate `xvfb` installed on Box B, and A is reachable (plus a decent connection) from B, the solution is simply to set:

```
DISPLAY=boxAHost:10
```

on Box B.

If A isn't reachable from B, it might be simplest to just duplicate the `xvfb` setup on both A and B, and have `DISPLAY=:10` on both.

Comment: see my updates to the question, there is only a single box. environment variables can be made specific to a a process, eg `DISPLAY=:10 protractor`

Comment: Any chance you could share a link to info about being able to link to a process (maybe on your answer)? I couldn't find it documented anywhere.

Comment: sorry @Andrew, I don't understand your question "link to a process". If you can clarify I'll happily provide any info I have. Do you mean; invoke chromedriver directly, rather than via a Selenium server? If so it's documented https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js see line 91'directConnect: false,'

Comment: My bad, I meant linking DISPLAY to a process name. Hosts, screens etc. I know, but I couldn't find anything about adding a proc name and how that would get used.