# Testing from different countries with protrator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

I want to do one test using protractor to check one website in different countries.

For example:

```
Scenario - Visitors get the expected language on first load

    Given: a visitor with IP from
                                   |UK|
                                   |SV|
                                   |NO|
                                   |FI|
                                   |ROW|

    When: loading the site for the first time

    Then: the language in dropdown will be 
                                           |English|
                                           |Svenska|
                                           |Norsk|
                                           |Suomi|
                                           |English|
```

Is possible use a FAKE ip in protractor tests? Other ideas to solve the problem?

Comment: Perhaps you should just change the browser's locale in the settings. Such as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26872481/activating-chrome-language-flags-when-activating-from-protractor-selenium

Comment: Thanks Thibs. This is really good advise but the website that I am testing do not use the locale setting to change the language. The website use the user ip to target language and other things like hide elements.